# How to Enable chrome-gnome-shell on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, chrome

This is an issue that has been brought up on other threads, but none of the answers seem to be working for me.  I just installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my machine and am trying to configure my desktop.  I want to enable gnome-shell-extensions for Firefox or Chromium and am having issues.  I can install chrome-gnome-shell with `apt` but it is not registering as integrating, and I get the following warning.

```
 Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.
```

I am aware that this is a support issue that started a little over a year ago.  However, on other distributions such as Arch Linux, there is a new package that can be installed from the Arch User Repository that fixed this issue.  I had assumed there would be something similar for Ubuntu.  I also reinstalled chrome-gnome-shell to see if that would fix the problem, but it is not.  What is the recommended way to get around this issue on Ubuntu?

Comment: Just came across the same problem and I think it's due to Firefox being installed as a snap package by default. The Firefox extension uses `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage` to communicate with the `chrome-gnome-shell` binary. The snap does not even know about this connection, because it can't access the config files. Switching to `apt` Firefox fixed it for me.